# Is it safe to do symlinks for the entire machine?

Tags: server, nfs, symbolic-link

I have a virtual machine with limited amount of storage which has become a problem. I have my home directory linked to NFS storage on a server and it has been functioning without a problem. But I now need to link my entire machine to the NFS as well as I am constantly running low on storage!

I am only wondering whether it is safe to link the entire machine (that is to say, the entire: **/** ) to the NFS?

I want to use the following commands to do that:

`/storage/nfs` is basically my mounted NFS.

```
$ mkdir /storage/nfs/myvmroot
$ sudo cp -rp /* /storage/nfs/myvmroot
$ sudo mv /* /old-root
$ sudo ln -s /storage/nfs/myvmroot /
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto - consider running a diskless install if even / needs to be mounted to nfs. You generally need support for nfs root.

Comment: I don't believe you can link / as parts are needed for boot. The largest space users ( /usr and /var) can be simlinked. Do you have a separate boot partition? Most space issues I have seen is a small /boot partition that is filled with multiple unused kernels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot make `/` a symbolic link. It just isn't possible. `/` has to be a directory. If `/` was a symbolic link, it would point to some path — and to resolve that path, the system would go through `/`, which is a symlink so needs to be resolved... A symlink that points under itself will always cause an error when it's dereferenced, but in any case, you won't be able to make `/` a symlink since it's already an existing directory.

What you can do, and will achieve the effect you wanted, is to [mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(Unix)) an NFS filesystem as the root filesystem, instead of mounting a local filesystem as is usually done. This is possible and supported by Ubuntu. [There's a tutorial on the Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto) (it covers a complete diskless installation, you can skip the parts about TFTP if you keep `/boot` locally). Moving an existing system is a bit different from doing the initial installation, so don't expect to follow the tutorial to the letter.

You need to ensure that the [initramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk) contains the necessary drivers. The initramfs is generated by the command [`update-initramfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/update-initramfs.8.html) based on the current system configuration and on the configuration files under `/etc/initramfs-tools`. You'll need to explicitly add NFS settings to [`/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/initramfs.conf.5.html), at least add a line `BOOT=nfs` (I think the other parameters can be specified at boot time, but `BOOT=nfs` is necessary in order to include the NFS drivers, and `DEVICE=…` may be necessary as well to include the Ethernet driver). Once you've modified `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`, run `update-initramfs`.

I recommend keeping `/boot` as a local partition, separate from `/`, if it isn't already.

**Do not use `cp -rp /* /storage/nfs/myvmroot` to copy files**, that would not work. You need to exclude mounted filesystems from the copy. Pass the `-x` option. Also, use `-a` rather than `-rp`, there are attributes that `-rp` doesn't preserve.

```
cp -ax /* /storage/nfs/myvmroot
```

or, in case the copy gets interrupted

```
rsync -axAX / /storage/nfs/myvmroot
```

---

Another, probably easier option is to keep the root filesystem local, and only move part of it. You'll generally get significantly better performance and reliability from a local filesystem than from NFS, even with a fast server and a fast network.

You can't just cut anywhere: what you put remotely must not be needed too early in the boot process. I think cutting at `/usr` is not officially supported by Ubuntu these days, but it is by Ubuntu's parent distribution Debian, so it has a chance of working. Another place that has a good chance of working is `/usr/share`. I don't recommend `/var`, it's likely to be a hassle if anything breaks since that's where logs are kept. (If the NFS client is unhappy about something and it tries to write logs to `/var/log` but `/var` isn't reponding, good luck diagnosing the failure.)

Comment: I changed the `rsync` command to use `/` instead of `/*`, because with `/*`, mounted locations like `/proc`, `/sys`, etc. won't run foul of the `-x` option.

Answer (score 10):

No. That would render your virtual machine unbootable. The NFS system is loaded at a certain point in the booting process. Before this point, no files on the NFS will be accessible.  This means that the machine won't be able to access the files it needs in order to boot. These include (but are not limited to) the kernel itself, the default shell `/bin/sh` and everything under `/bin` which includes the commands needed in order to mount the NFS share.

So no, this is not a good idea. More importantly, it isn't necessary. Most of the directories in `/` are not very big. Just identify the one that is taking up the space and put that one there. You should be able to move either of the following with no major issues:

- `/var/cache`
- `/usr/local`
- `/usr` itself can also usually be moved but make sure nothing essential is in `/usr/local/bin`. It probably won't be, but check.

Those are probably the ones taking up the space anyway.

Comment: It might be possible with the right initramfs. For example, it's possible to [live boot ISOs across a network served by tftpd and NFS](https://askubuntu.com/a/537096/158442)

Comment: @muru ah yes, which is presumably why things like netinstall are possible. Good point.

Comment: “No” is misleading — the answer to the question as asked is “[mu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mu#Etymology_2)”, because it's impossible, so it can't be rated as “safe” or “unsafe”. What follows is wrong. It is perfectly possible to put the root filesystem on NFS, and it is supported by Ubuntu (you just have to convince the initramfs builder to include the relevant driver). I don't know whether Ubuntu supports `/var` on a separate partition from `/`; that requires care in boot scripts, so if it isn't officially supported, it probably doesn't work.

Comment: @Gilles yes, I have answered the question assuming the OP wants to just take their already existing install and simply move everything under `/` to NFS with no other changes. Granted, regenerating an initramfs with the correct settings should work but that wasn't what was asked in the question. Note the commands.  I also changed my suggestion to `/var/cache` instead of `/var` to be on the safe side and since that's probably where the culprit is, but why would `/var` be needed during boot and before NFS drives are mounted?